# Dates changing its format when showing on .jsp

Tags: date, struts2, locale

I have a class which retrieves its data from the database. One of the attributes of the object of the model is a `java.sql.Date`, which stores the date as `yyyy-mm-dd` (as `System.out.println` shows).

When in my `.jsp` pages I read that information, it shows it as `d/mm/yy` without my intervention. I suppouse it's because of my locale configuration (`es-ES`). I want to rewrite that in order to show `dd/mm/yyyy`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you using to show dates on JSP?

Comment: Just `<s:property value="date" />`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To show dates on JSP use Struts2 [`<s:date>`](http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/date.html) tag which has `format` attribute.

```
<s:date name="date" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

With `<s:date>` tag you can also use `struts.date.format` in your properties file to define default date format.